# Configuration Spring MVC without web.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-framework-beans

I'm trying to send requests to my RestController, but it's not working, i have

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(
    value = "/cursos",
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,
    consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE
)
public class CursoRestController {

@Autowired
private CursoService cursoService;

@GetMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public List<Curso> listAll() {
    System.out.println("Test");
    return cursoService.findAll();
}

@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Void> save(@RequestBody Curso curso) {
    cursoService.save(curso);
    URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(curso.getId()).toUri();
    return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
}
```

I'm using Postman to send request, and when i send some request i get 400 error code, with no message or something to tell to me, what's happing, BUT when i try to open the same URL on the browser, I GET THE RESPONSE, i don't if i configured something wrong, i'm using theses classes to config my project

SpringRootConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("br.com.gabriel.restful")
public class SpringRootConfig {



}
```

SpringInitConfig

```
public class SpringInitConfig extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{SpringRootConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }
}
```

SpringJpaConfig

```
@Configuration
public class SpringJpaConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/wildbuild");
        ds.setUsername("postgres");
        ds.setPassword("admin");
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory =  new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setPackagesToScan("br.com.gabriel.restful.domain");
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager(){
        JpaTransactionManager manager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        manager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        manager.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
        return manager;
    }

    private Properties jpaProperties(){
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        props.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        return props;
    }

}
```

My project have this structure:
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZtee.png)

Comment: The thing is if you got a **400 error status code** it means a `Bad request` i.e your syntax of the request is incorrect. If you are able to run this on the browser then, one thing is for sure there's nothing wrong with the code. So look out for requests made in postman or try sending a reference image so we can understand how you're making your request to the controller.

Comment: I'm sending this request, here is my documentation in postman: https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/13485869/UzJMsvnW